# Kademi - allow front end user to delete a file they have uploaded

Tags: kademi

I am trying to allow front end user to delete a file they have uploaded.

`#docs()` tells me that `$page.lead.files` has a method called `.remove()` that accepts either an Int or an Object.

I keep getting a response of "false" when using this method. I am trying to pass and ID or Object of a file within `$page.lead.files` object.

**Debugging...**
User: https://spinsurance.admin.kademi.com.au/manageUsers/116783806/#summary-tab
Page: https://crm.spinsurance.co.nz/leads/148615383/
Source: https://spinsurance.admin.kademi.com.au/repositories/spcrm/version1/theme/apps/leadman/components/texteditor?fileName=leadDetailTabContentComponent.html

Under section on page called: **Uploaded File**s.
Click big red Delete button. (I don't mind if this file gets deleted)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lead.files property is a persisted list. Its not a good idea to try to modify the database using that approach.

Note that lead files are exposed as http addressable resources, which support the http DELETE method

So the simplest approach is to delete from the browser using ajax

Eg

```
DELETE /leads/123/myfile.pdf
```